# Cannot Build a C++ Project?

Tags: c++

The project is imported and guaranteed to be fault-free. However, I cannot build it into `.exe` using Visual Studio Professional 2013 RC.

I end up with 3 errors. Since as mentioned it is error-free on the code aspect, I guess the problems are just some minor organization faults.

[image]

What are the **possible causes** for the 3 errors?

1. `_main already defined in Main.obj`
2. `unresolved external symbol`
3. `1 unresolved externals`

**What may I do to fix it?**

Comment: What does Param.h / Param.cpp contain? A main function?

Comment: Googling for those errors should have given you a ton of answers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is designed to be used in a console application, but you have put it into a GUI subsystem project.

Switch to targetting the console subsystem. In the Linker options, select the System page and change the SubSystem setting to Console. Alternatively, start again with a new project, but select a console application when working your way through the new project wizard.

On top of that it would seem that you have another `main` defined somewhere in your code. You need to define exactly one `main` function. Clearly you'll need to find that other `main` and work out what to do with it. The error message is telling you that the linker found it in `Param.obj`. So, I suggest you take a look at `Param.cpp`.

Comment: Yes, Param.cpp indeed has another main inside. http://pastie.org/8371765 What may I do? Really urgent to run the code and fail to contact the author. Thanks

Comment: You are only allowed one `main`. Which one do you want to use? Honestly, I cannot advise you on that since I've no domain knowledge. I've just answered the question you asked about where the errors come from. Quite possibly you are expected to include one or other of those files in the project, but not both. But hey, I cannot tell from here.

Comment: Thanks! The difference is that the Main.cpp takes more arguments. So I guess I will use it. Then what should I do with Param.cpp?

Comment: Remove that from the project.

Comment: Delete the whole Param.cpp?

Comment: You just need to remove it from your project. Right click on it in the solution explorer, and then select remove. Deleting the file from disk would also get it done, but you just need to tell VS to stop compiling and linking that file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38477/discussion-between-perfectionm1ng-and-david-heffernan)